# ROS_INFO not printing anything after some point

Tags: ros, rosconsole

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my code below, constructor of a class calls functions within the same class. All `ROS_INFO` in func1 print successfully but func2 doesn't print anything. Any idea?

Update 8/13/2012) Each action server is robot manipulation, which means there's fair amount of time before func2 gets called after func1.

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <actionlib/client/simple_action_client.h>
#include <actionlib/client/terminal_state.h>
#include <pointcloud_filter/PointCloudFilterBoxAction.h>
#include <pointcloud_filter/PointCloudFilterBoxGoal.h>
#include <pointcloud_segmenter/RGBPointCloudSegmenterAction.h>
#include <pointcloud_segmenter/RGBPointCloudSegmenterGoal.h>

class OurClass
{
public:
    static const double DURATION = 30.0;
    OurClass()
    {
        this->func1();
        this->func2();
    }
    void func1()
    {
        ROS_INFO("msg 1-0");
        actionlib::SimpleActionClient<ourns::OurAction> ac("ourAction", true);
        bool finished_before_timeout = ac.waitForResult(ros::Duration(DURATION));
        if (finished_before_timeout)
        {
            actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState state = ac.getState();
            ROS_INFO("msg 1-1");
        }
        else
            ROS_INFO("msg 1-2");
    }

    void func2()
    {
        ROS_INFO("msg 2-0 ");
        actionlib::SimpleActionClient<pointcloud_filter::PointCloudFilterBoxAction> ac_filter("PointCloudFilterBox", true);
        ac_filter.sendGoal(goal_filter);
        bool finished_before_timeout2 = ac_filter.waitForResult(ros::Duration(DURATION));
        if (finished_before_timeout2)
        {
            actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState state = ac_filter.getState();
            ROS_INFO("2-1");
        }
        else
            ROS_INFO("2-2");
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "AcClient");
    OurClass();
}
```

Environment) `fuerte`, Ubuntu 10.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41228/ros_info-not-printing-anything-after-some-point/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2012-08-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If the code you posted really is 'all there is', then it seems to at least be missing a `ros::spin()` or similar statement. If the ros event loop is run somewhere else, the `ros::init(..)` seems out of place.

What is most likely going on is that the ros logging subsystem has 'enough' time to flush out the `ROS_INFO(..)` calls in `func1()`, but not for those in `func2()`. I've noticed this myself a few times, especially when trying to print some output at node(let) shutdown (to print statistics for instance).

Suggestions I've received included 'sleeping some time' before calling `ros::shutdown(..)` (if doing so explicitly) or before returning from your `main`.

---

Originally posted by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) with karma: 1416 on 2012-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-03-28**:
Looks reasonable explanation although I can't test it since I don't have an access to the environment I was seeing the phenomenon...